# Finding the proportionality constant of the Quantum Angular Momentum raising operator $T_{+}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, lie-algebra

This is a question about the mathematics of angular momentum operators in Quantum Mechanics- specifically a recursive relation from Robert Cahn's Semi-Simple Lie Algebras and their Representations page 5.

Some Background Math:

$T_{+}=T_x+iT_y$

$T_{-}=T_x-iT_y$

$[T_z,T_+]=T_+\;\;\;[T_z,T_+]=T_1\;\;\;[T_+,T_-]=2T_z$

$T_{z}v_{j}=jv_j\;\;\;T_+v_j=0$

$T_z T_{+}v_{k}=(j+1)v_k$

and assuming,

$r_j=0$

From

$r_{k}v_{k+1}=T_{+}v_k=T_{+}T_{-}v_{k+1}=(T_{-}T_{+}+2T_z)v_{k+1}=[r_{k+1}+2(k+1)]v_{k+1}$

the recursive relation is

$r_{k}=r_{k+1}+2(k+1)$

and this is satisfied by

$r_k=j(j+1)-k(k+1)$

My question is about this last formula. This is my incomplete proof:

From

$r_{k}=r_{k+1}+2(k+1)$ or

$r_{k+1}=r_k-2(k+1)$

$r_1=r_0-2(0+1)$

$r_2=r_1-2(1+1)$

$r_3=r_2-2(2+1)$

$r_4=r_3-2(3+1)$

Therefore,

$r_4=r_0-2(0+1)-2(1+1)-2(2+1)-2(3+1)=r_0-2[1+2+3+4]$

By algebra, applying the Gauss formula for the sum $1+2+3+4=4(4+1)/2$, and taking $4=k$,

$r_k=r_{0}-(k+1)k$

What is $r_0$?

Comment: It seems to me that by removing that line, you've gone from asking a question to providing some mathematical relations w/o asking a question on a Q&A site.

Comment: @KyleKanos The question of what $r_0$ is remains. It's very possible that people reading this book will stumble across this via google. I would rather not confuse them with  nonsense in the question itself. I isolated the real question from the part of the question that was based on an algebra mistake.

Comment: Yes, you *just* added in that question a minute after you wrote the above comment. That does not erase the fact that your first edit removed the existence of *any* question.

Comment: @KyleKanos I added that for clarity. The question was implicit because I was asking about the relation given in which $r_0=j(j+1)$ and I said my proof was incomplete. Obviously I'm asking for the complete proof.

Comment: No, it wasn't implicit, it just didn't exist. You said "My question is about this relation" which could be about *many* aspects of the relation and since you didn't specify, it was completely unclear.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thought it was clear. You told me it wasn't. I clarified it. Now you are complaining about the clarification. In the end, this is a potentially useful post.

Comment: No, I'm complaining that your first comment suggested that it was always there when it clearly wasn't & your subsequent defense of that indefensible position.

Comment: @KyleKanos I wouldn't say it's indefensible. I still believe the most natural interpretation is that I'm asking for $r_0$. I just don't really care to defend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is trivial because I made small math errors and did not apply the condition that $r_j=0$.

$r_j=0=r_0-j(j+1)$

Therefore $r_0=j(j+1)$